# Calibre Author handling

Tags: python-2.7, metadata, calibre

Is it possible to attach some information to an Author (picture, bio, link to personal site, etc) and have it display on every book from that author?

Author(s) seem to be "embedded" in each book.

Am I missing something?

Note: I'm trying to automatize translation of an existing archive to calibre, so I'm interested in programmatic interface to Authors (I found none specific, just Book Metadata).